# View css not going till the top Iphone X

Tags: css, react-native, expo

[Screen Shot of Iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPUow.png) Iv'e been trying to make my view background color go till the top on the iPhone x but still can figure out how to do this I still have a white section on the top.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react- 
native'
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
  // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  //   this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'Main' : 'Login')
  // }) // for now to solve problem 
  } 
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Loading</Text>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
    </View>
   )
 }
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#2C3E50',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
}
});
```

I would very much like the background color to go to the top as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run your code but I'm assuming that the issue is the switchNavigator is showing a header. If this is the case then you want to change the color of the navigator within the screen that you are on.

So within your Loading class:

```
export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    // Add this:
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#2C3E50',
        },
    };
    componentDidMount() {} 
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Loading</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#adjusting-header-styles

Answer (score 0):

That may be header of stack navigator(very less probability).. or may be with "safeViewiOS"... This may be also a issue with react navigation. Using flex:1 usually takes the screen acc to flex property .. This is surely a inherited property. not a problem with flex or CSS

Try adding :

```
forceInset={{ bottom: 'never', top: "never" }}>
```